# How to capture/log Android reboot cause

Tags: android, android-debug

While developing my android custom ROM, I need to know that - is there
a way to log or capture the cause of android reboot, whether user
manually powered off / rebooted the devices or wether system_server
got restarted by adb kill or it was watchdog who restarted the device.

Help Appreciated !
Thanks

Comment: Does anyone has any idea on this..?

Answer (score 2):

use this command in adb shell:

```
cat /proc/last_kmsg
```

you can see the cause of last reboot

Comment: This path does not exist for me. (LineageOS 20 / Android 13 / GSI).